# Can I my current theme call in constructing In custom Magento extension?

Tags: extensions

```
  public function _construct(){

     $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();

}

public function indexAction(){

    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();

    echo "see My Controller";
}
```

When I am call layout in index controller the it will display the my cuttent theme. and when I call in _construct then it's display magento default theme. why?
can you explain ? how to set my current theme in _construct() function magento extension

Comment: Try to add this line `Mage::app()->loadArea($this->getLayout()->getArea());` before `loadLayout`

Comment: I will add it as an answer. I added it as a comment because it was a shot in the dark. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add

```
Mage::app()->loadArea($this->getLayout()->getArea());
```

in your constructor before loading the layout.
That line is needed so magento will know what area to load.
It works in an action because the action is called after `preDispatch()` is called, and that's where the area is usually loaded.

It doesn't work in the constructor by default because the constructor is called prior to calling `preDispatch()`